# C# How to write to a byte array starting from index x

Tags: c#, networking, tcp

I have a custom protocol to send and receive messages over TCP like the following:

The first 4 bytes is the message type, the following 4 bytes is the length of the message and the rest of the buffer is containing the message itself.

```
 private byte[] CreateMessage(int mtype,string data)
 {

        byte[] buffer = new byte[4 + 4 + data.Length];

       //write mtype, data.Length, and data to buffer

        return buffer;

 }
```

I want to write mtype to the first 4 bytes of buffer and then data.Length to next 4 bytes and then the data. I am coming from golang world and we do that like the following:

```
buf := make([]byte, 4+4+len(data))
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(buf[0:], uint32(mtype))
binary.LittleEndian.PutUint32(buf[4:], uint32(len(data)))
```

Comment: So basically you're asking how to convert an int to a byte[4] with some certain order to the bytes?

Comment: Perhaps just use a BinaryWriter, and write the ints to the network stream; they'll end up as byte sequences on the wire ..

Comment: @CaiusJard in all seriousness: in something like 18 years specialising in .NET IO code (serializers, network code, etc): I have yet to find a scenario where BinaryWriter is the correct answer to any requirement

Answer (score 1):

```cs
Span<byte> span = buffer;
BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt32LittleEndian(span, type);
BinaryPrimitives.WriteUInt32LittleEndian(span.Slice(4), (uint)len);
// etc
```

A span is sort of like an array, and you can create a span from an array..but a span can be sliced internally. Not all APIs work with spans, but those that do ... sweet.